# Django REST Framework: Nested relationships only on read

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a few related models and I wanted to have related object information nested into the read so I followed the example outlined here:

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships

A couple of my serializers look like this:

```
class ShowSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    artists = ArtistSerializer(many=True)
    venue = VenueSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Show


class GuestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    show = serializers.RelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model = Guest
```

And when I read them (GET), they're perfect, the output is something like:

```
"results": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "show": {
            "id": 2,
            "artists": [
                {
                    "id": 13,
                    "name": "Some Artist"
                }
            ],
            "venue": {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Some Venue",
            },
            "date": "2015-11-20"
        },
        "first_name": "Amanda",
        "last_name": "Hugankiss",
    }
]
```

The problem I'm having is when I POST, this configuration seems to expect an entire nested structure just as above, where I'd prefer to specify an id for a relationship on POST, like so:

```
{
    "show": 16,
    "first_name": "Maya",
    "last_name": "Normusbutt",
}
```

Is there a way to configure my serializers/view (by the way, I'm using `ModelViewSet`) to do this?

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26899976/django-rest-framework-when-to-create-a-hyperlinked-resource-and-when-nested-res/35667679#35667679)